# Trying to join a channel in freenode

Tags: irc

I'm trying to connect to a channel in freenode using xchat but I'm getting this:

```
Invalid password for my_nickname.
```

Any idea?

**NOTE**: I'm asking here because I didn't find a good place to ask.. Please, recommend me a place to ask about freenode if you consider this is not the right place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you get that error on all channels?
otherwise there might be a password on the channel

could also be that you didn't identify to the nickserver and freenode doesn't let you join anything (not familair with freenode)

please explain some more or past some RAW code when you try to join a channel with that error

Answer (score 0):

It means that you provided an incorrect password to NickServ. If you saved your password in xchat you may want to check to see if it is still valid. If you have forgotten your password, hop in #freenode and ask for password reset.